How can I access my Google Nest Aware video history via API?
I have an active Google Nest Aware subscription and want to retrieve video history (recordings and events) through an API. I know that some integrations are available via Google Assistant, but I'm looking specifically for ways to access or retrieve full video history, if possible, in a third-party app. Has anyone managed to access Nest Aware video feeds or recordings through an API? If not, are there any workarounds or solutions for this?, i need to build a backend
Still figuring it out, couldn't find anything on API

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

I'm looking for a similar solution, having just bought a Nest doorbell with the mistaken assumption that it would save 3 hours of cumulative video and not just the last 3 hours in time. This post isn't pretty, but it has some good ideas: https://medium.com/@tamirmayer/google-nest-camera-internal-api-fdf9dc3ce167

I am trying to find the same but it appears that it isn't possible. Nest doesn't officially offer a public API for their Nest Aware platform, which includes security camera footage and activity data, due to privacy and security concerns. Since Google acquired Nest and integrated it into Google’s ecosystem, they’ve significantly limited third-party access, moving most device management to the Google Home API.
But if you found a solution!
